# Tags for Word, term or phrase for idioms, proverbs, figure-of-speech that lose true meaning due to being from a different time or due to translation

Tags: feature-request

Since biblical hermeneutics involves words, terms, phrases, idioms, proverbs, figure-of-speech, etc., can lose their true meaning because

•   it meant something in a different time period

•   it was being translated from one language to another

Therefore, could the website moderators  include some or all of the following terms/phrases  as tags for the https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/ website?

( Credit Reference:    https://english.stackexchange.com/a/607799/199729   )

> diachronic semasiology -  "What does X mean" changes depending on the
> era
>
> diachronic onomasiology - "How do you express X" changes over time
>
> semantic drift

( Credit Reference:   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skunked_term  )

> skunked term is a word that becomes difficult to use because it is
> transitioning from one meaning to another, perhaps inconsistent or
> even opposite, usage, or a word that becomes difficult to use due to
> other controversy surrounding the word. Purists may insist on the old
> usage, while descriptivists may be more open to newer usages. Readers
> may not know which sense is meant especially when prescriptivists
> insist on a meaning that accords with interests that often conflict.
>
> The term was coined by lexicographer Bryan A. Garner in Garner's
> Modern American Usage and has since been adopted by some other style
> guides.

could the website moderators  include some or all of the above terms/phrases  as tags for the https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/ website?

Answer (score 2):

Normal members can create tags and you already have enough rep points to do so.

But tags can only be created by adding them to questions. We can't create them ahead of time.

Of those terms, semantic drift seems reasonable and somewhat of a supercase of the others. The others are probably too obscure to be understood and useful here. Not every precise term in linguistics needs to be a tag.

Answer (score 0):

There is no purpose of that tag for semantics linguistics here as they belong to those like English and Linguistics SE, if you want to discuss the semantic change in KJV vocabulary with modern English. If you already know about the semantic change in word then you shouldn't use that tag in that question. Word-study already exist as the relevant tag if the question is about word study.

Answer (score -1):

Some would disagree that scripture falls into this category of literature since it is very clear that unchangeable concepts are being expressed in Hebrew and then in Greek.

Scripture is remarkable in that concepts are enshrined in words which are suited to the concepts.

What this question is describing is the *corruption of language* whereas in scripture we see the *preservation of concepts* from one language (Hebrew) to another (Greek).